# Parsing raw response data from POST request (R)

Tags: r

I am trying to scrape a table of recent events from the following link: https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter

When visiting the link, the table shows upcoming events, so you have to click under schedule and change the option to "result".

I have scraped what appears to be the raw data below in the variable ***resp***, but I don't know what language that code is written in and don't know how to parse it.

```r
library(httr)

url <- paste0("https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter_events")

fd <- list(
  group = "all",
  region = "",
  schedule = "results",
  sport = "all"
)

postdata <- POST(url = url, query = fd, encode = "form",
                 add_headers(
                   "Accept" = "text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01",
                   "Content-Type" = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                   "Cookie" = "_ga=GA1.2.1873043703.1537368153; __utmz=88071069.1563301531.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); remember_id=149246; remember_token=315e68b7a95fa6cda391fc3e2ae0e1fb1466335ed9a15480558bd4ef8d52d832; __utmc=88071069; __utma=88071069.1873043703.1537368153.1563983348.1563985208.3; _tapology_mma_session=Z2RWaU1XZ0hOQmIwcUhjN1Bac0twN0JZQktnVUlLUjVsVkdMMDR4bTBITGdnSDFlRW9WeHprQ2lRaWdJM0lRbW5PNTFYSG9kbVlaMWFlR3liZmEyZWhnRWVVNm03UVIwRUJLWHl1MmJXRlQ1dEFJTGJsTnVLQWx4MWpUMTJOYlBxQ1N1Y0pQREZlZTNzMDA0NTJINEpLS2FMNXZvaXZjQ3g2dFMzM1dJeTRmekc4TG5JTk9YZDlZdWx5WnpZd3luZlY1ZXliQ0RWS1B1aXJYQnpqVVp4UT09LS10am5XNVI0c0pXa2p1dHJ5OW9PME5nPT0%3D--7488fef85f733279f15da594ea47f0345aa16938",
                   "Host" = "www.tapology.com",
                   "Origin" = "https://www.tapology.com",
                   "User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36",
                   "Referer" = "https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter",
                   "X-CSRF-Token" = "NS9M1Y5RMShdIfFaIKpYiqr+JuOZ8kwZvn9KSW7daZmgT9eJ4Q0ZyGLZSUHR4wjCdiE840HcQzLHHZSe0WgVJw==",
                   "X-Requested-With" = "XMLHttpRequest"
                   )
)

resp <- content(postdata, "text")

substr(resp, 1, 200)
[1] "$(\".fightcenterEvents\").html(\"<h3>\\n<span>Event Results<\\/span>\\n<span class=\\'moreLink\\'>  <nav class=\\\"pagination\\\" role=\\\"navigation\\\" aria-label=\\\"pager\\\">\\n    \\n    \\n        <span class=\\\"page "
```

Comment: you should probably not share your token. The code you are receiving in is in HTML. Use VS studio code or notebook+ to read that code

Comment: It's JavaScript that contains some HTML. You can extract the HTML and parse it, but it is meant to be processed by JavaScript, so it has escapes etc. that make it hard to extract nodes. It also has an odd nested structure. You might want to give RSelenium a try.

Comment: @gersht I extracted only the content contained in the html tag deleted all the newlines. Then I was able to use read_html and parse the contents that way.

Comment: Good to hear. When I parsed it the parser complained because of the depth. I could still parse it but when I extracted the nodes I got data in data in data etc. – that's why thought it might be better to try something else. But if it works then there's no reason.